# Optimizing a Bit-Wise Manipulation Kernel

Tags: optimization, cuda, bit-manipulation

I have the following code which progressively goes through a string of bits and rearrange them into blocks of 20bytes. I'm using 32*8 blocks with 40 threads per block. However the process takes something like 36ms on my GT630M. Are there any further optimization I can do? Especially with regard to removing the if-else in the inner most loop.

```
__global__ void test(unsigned char *data)
{
    __shared__ unsigned char dataBlock[20];
    __shared__ int count;
    count = 0;

    unsigned char temp = 0x00;

    for(count=0; count<(streamSize/8); count++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            if(blockIdx.y >= i)
                temp |= (*(data + threadIdx.x*(blockIdx.x + gridDim.x*(i+count)))&(0x01<<blockIdx.y))>>(blockIdx.y - i);
            else
                temp |= (*(data + threadIdx.x*(blockIdx.x + gridDim.x*(i+count)))&(0x01<<blockIdx.y))<<(i - blockIdx.y); 
        }
        dataBlock[threadIdx.x] = temp;  
            //do something

    }

}
```

Comment: You could start by *always* using block sizes which are round multiples of the warp size. Using 40 threads per block is wasting about 37% of all the available cycles on your GPU.

Comment: Also you may want to launch many threads in block at the same time to hide latences.

Comment: Your outer loop writes `dataBlock[threadIdx.x] = temp;` every iteration -- so you are overwriting the same location `streamSize/8` times. Move that line outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your code is trying to accomplish, but a couple obvious opportunities are:

1) if possible, use 32-bit words instead of unsigned char.

2) use block sizes that are multiples of 32.

3) The conditional code may not be costing you as much as you expect.  You can check by compiling with --cubin --gpu-architecture sm_xx (where xx is the SM version of your target hardware), and using cuobjdump --dump-sass on the resulting cubin file to look at the generated assembly.  You may have to modify the source code to loft the common subexpression into a separate variable, and/or use the ternary operator ? : to hint to the compiler to use predication.

Comment: And ideally use at least 64 threads per block.  32-thread blocks on sm_30 and earlier devices will limit occupancy (and therefore ability to cover memory latency) since each SM can have at most 8 resident blocks.  With 32 threads per block you will therefore have at most 8 warps per SM, whereas you'll have 16 if you use 64-thread blocks.